# boto3 signed url resulting in SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

My code is successfully uploading documents into the correct bucket. I can login and see the docs in the buckets on AWS S3. When I try to use the generate_signed_url method in boto3 to obtain a URL for these documents that can then be sent to users for accessing the doc, I'm getting a SignatureDoesNotMatch with the message saying "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

When i save the object (verified that it is working correctly by logging into AWS and downloading the files manually), I use:

```
  s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-2', aws_access_key_id='XXXX', aws_secret_access_key='XXXX', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

  s3.put_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name,Key=path, Body=temp_file.getvalue(),ACL='public-read')
```

Then, when I try to get the URL, I'm using:

```
  s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-2', aws_access_key_id='XXXX', aws_secret_access_key='XXXX', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

  url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        'put_object', Params={
        'Bucket':self.pdffile_storage_bucket_name, 
        'Key':self.pdffile_url
        },
        ExpiresIn=604799,
    )
```

I saw quite a bit of users on the web talking about making sure your AWS access key doesn't include any special characters. I did this, and I still get the same issue.

Comment: Have a look at the request headers when using your pre-signed URL. In my case `Content-Type` was being sent along and I needed to add it to the URL generation as well, because AWS checks it.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien can you advise on how i can go about looking at these request headers? I haven't done that before. Thanks for your help here.

Comment: You're creating a link to perform a `PUT`, i.e. to let users upload a document to a pre-defined key in the bucket. What's easiest depends on where they will be doing that from. In fact, is it what you want at all? You said you want to provide access to the document. Are you trying to download (`GET`) using a link that was meant for uploads? That won't work. In that case you should be creating the link with `'get_object'` rather than `'put_object'`. Also note that the `'Key'` should be just that; no URL but what you passed in (`path`) when uploading.

Comment: On another note, expiring pre-signed URLs are useless when public users have access anyway. Whoever knows both the bucket name and the key can download the file indefinitely. You might as well provide a direct unsigned link if you don't mind that. Otherwise, remove the permanent ACL—the expiring pre-signed URL serves as temporary permission.

Answer (score 4):

I tried many solutions from many different places. None of the worked for me. Then i got a solution on GitHub, that worked for me. [Here](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1149#issuecomment-577177210) is the original solution, just copy pasting his solution.

```py
s3 = boto3.client(
    's3', region_name='us-east-2',
    aws_access_key_id='XXXX', aws_secret_access_key='XXXX',
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'),
    endpoint_url='https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
)
```

Comment: In my case, I wanted a URL anyone can read from, but I mistakenly generated an s3 URL anyone can write to. In my stupidity, I uploaded the data via requests library and kept attempting to read the same via the resigned_url.

But eventually, the correct thing to do was to firstly upload the file to s3 via boto3, then generate a presigned URL with read permission. So, ultimately, I used `get_object` instead of `put_object` .

`"S3.generate_presigned_url('get_object',Params={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': object_name}, ExpiresIn=expiration)"`

Answer (score 2):

You are generating a pre-signed URL for an upload, not a download.  You don't want `put_object` here... it's `get_object`.

Also, as @ThijsvanDien pointed out, `ACL='public-read'` may not be what you want, when uploading -- this makes the object accessible to anyone with an unsigned URL.

Comment: If I'm ok with public read access, why might my URL still show up as Access Denied? I hard coded in a url format with the key, and I'm getting Access Denied even though I did a public read ACL when I put the object.

Comment: Just an outright "Access Denied" error with no explanation?  Examine the object with the console.  Be sure the path is the way you expect it and check its permissions.

Answer (score 2):

(after 3+ hours of debugging and almost smashing the keyboard....)

in the response, it's telling you which header is missing:

```xml
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
    <!-- .... -->
    <CanonicalRequest>PUT (your pre-signed url)
    content-type:image/jpeg
    host:s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
    x-amz-acl:

    content-type;host;x-amz-acl
    UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest>
```

Needed a `x-amz-acl` header matching the ACL set when generating the pre-signed URL

```py
def python_presign_url():
    return s3.generate_presigned_url('put_object', Params={
        'Bucket': bucket_name,
        'Key': filename,
        'ContentType': type,
        'ACL':'public-read' # your x-amz-acl
    })
```

```
curl -X PUT \
    -H "content-type: image/jpeg" \
    -H "Host: s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com" \
    -H "x-amz-acl: public-read" \
    -d @/path/to/upload/file.jpg "$PRE_SIGNED_URL"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a trailing space on my secret access key variable. That was causing the issue. E.g:
AWS_SECRET_KEY = "xyz "

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, adding parameter `config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')` when creating the boto3 client (or boto3 Session) fixed this error.

Note also that Config is located in botocore.client